# Unable to remove fragment from transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, I need to remove a set of fragments from transaction when the OS recreate my app due to configuration change. I'm trying to do it as following;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();

        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                if (!((fragment instanceof FragmentType1) ||
                        (fragment instanceof FragmentType2) ||
                        (fragment instanceof FragmentType3))) {
                    FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction();
                    trans.remove(fragment).commit();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Though `trans.remove(fragment).commit()` is executed successfully, but debugging shows that these fragments are still there in `FragmentManager`. Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: How the fragments are added? post fragment added code once

Comment: @HarshaVardhan, Fragments were added like `transaction.add(fragContainer.getId(), fragment1)`